# How to call PDOStatement::nextRowset() in Cakephp 3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pdo, cakephp-3.0

I have created a procedure in which i there are two select statements are running.

```
$stmt = $this->_connection->execute("CALL myFunction(:user_id)", [
    'user_id' => $userId
]);
```

But when i am trying to call the nextRowset() like this

```
$stmt->nextRowset();
```

Its giving me error

> Call to undefined method Cake\Database\Log\LoggingStatement::nextRowset()

So, My question is how can i call the nextRowset() in Cakephp 3

Comment: Are you sure `$stmt` is a pdoStmt?

Comment: @u_mulder No it isn't, as you can see from the error. I don't know the way in cakephp 3 to get the pdostmt.

Comment: You can't unless you have own implementation of StatementInterface. Basically you need to extend cake's PDOStatement to get access to raw \PDOStatement.

Comment: @AlexBlex So there is no straight way? Should i edit the core files of cakephp ?

Comment: No there is no straight way. Changing framework's files is the least recommended way. Try to extend core classes and make the framework use them instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that all core statement classes do extend `\Cake\Database\Statement\StatementDecorator` at some point, you could get to the underlying native `\PDOStatement` object via `StatementDecorator::getInnerStatement()`, like:

```
while ($stmt instanceof StatementDecorator) {
    $stmt = $stmt->getInnerStatement();
}

if (!($stmt instanceof \PDOStatement)) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Expected an instance of \PDOStatement');
}
```

Then you can use standard PDO statement procedures, like iterating over the rowsets in a loop:

```
do {
    $rowset = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // ...
} while ($stmt->nextRowset());
```

As already mentioned in the comments, another way would be to implement your own statement class (and make your code expect an instance of that concrete implementation). For cross DB compatibilty you'd have to implement four different statements though, plus four drivers where you'd re-implement `\Cake\Database\Driver::prepare()`, as this is where the statement instances are being generated.

Also in case you want to support query logging, you'd have to create a custom connection class and override `\Cake\Database\Connection::prepare()` or `\Cake\Database\Connection::_newLogger()`, as this is where the statements generated by driver are being wrapped in `\Cake\Database\Log\LoggingStatement` in case query logging is enabled.

I'd say if all you want to support are the built-in drivers, then expecting `\Cake\Database\Statement\StatementDecorator` instances is probably the better choice for the time being, even though it's not overly nice. You may want to [**suggest adding functionality**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues) for advancing multi-rowset statements as an enhancement, not sure if there will be much support for it though.

See also

- **[API > \Cake\Database\Statement\StatementDecorator::getInnerStatement()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Database.Statement.StatementDecorator.html#_getInnerStatement)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Driver::prepare()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Database.Driver.html#_prepare)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Connection::prepare()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Database.Connection.html#_prepare)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Connection::_newLogger()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Database.Connection.html#__newLogger)**

Comment: Thanks mate it worked. Can i do it like this `while (!($stmt instanceof \PDOStatement)) { $stmt = $stmt->getInnerStatement(); }` instead of throwing exception

Comment: @AmanRawat I wouldn't recommend that, it's way less failsafe, as it doesn't check whether `$stmt` is a `StatementDecorator`, ie whether it's safe to call `getInnerStatement()`. You surely don't need to throw an exception, this was just an example, you can of course choose a less invasive error handling, like returning `false`, showing a flash message, etc, it all depends on the context where you'd use that code.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks