# Not able to access multiple result rowsets from stored procedure in CakePHP 3.4

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pdo, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to access multiple result sets returned from a stored procedure in my CakePHP 3.4 project. Here is my code:

```
$stmt = $db->execute("call mydatasp($paramlist)");
    $result = array();                     
    try{
            do
            {
                $rowset = $stmt->fetchAll('assoc');
                $result[]=$rowset;
            } while($stmt->nextRowset());
        }
        catch(Exception $e){}
```

I have done a lot of search andalso gone through this link but didn't find any useful data. [How to call PDOStatement::nextRowset() in Cakephp 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158753/how-to-call-pdostatementnextrowset-in-cakephp-3/51985580)

How can I do this?

Comment: So what's the problem with using the code in the answer to the question that you've linked?

Comment: @ndm thanks for your quick reply. I have tried the code, but its giving me only first result set not all. Here is my code. In $result array i m getting only first resultset - try{
                do
                {
                    $rowset = $stmt->fetchAll('assoc');                                                              
                    $result[]=$rowset;                                  
                } while($stmt instanceof StatementDecorator);
            }

Comment: I see, that's not how you'd use it. You'd use it to extract the innermost PDO statement from the statement decorator (`$stmt`) that you receive from the `execute()` call, and then you can iterate over it with your original `do...while` loop.

Comment: I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158753/how-to-call-pdostatementnextrowset-in-cakephp-3/51985580) with a further example to make it a little more clear.

Comment: That indicates that you did not use the code from my answer.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, was busy in some other stuff. @ndm I refer your code and try to implement it, but it is not working for me. I am missing something and can not figure it out. Still getting the error - Call to undefined method Cake\Database\Log\LoggingStatement::nextRowset().  It will be helpful if you can explain it with some running example code. Thank you –

Answer (score 0):

```
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');

$sql = "CALL test()"; // name of stored procedure

$rowSet = 1; //default value is 1,change according to stored procedure result set to access multiple result

$stmt = $connection->execute($sql)->getInnerStatement()->getInnerStatement();

for ($i = 0; $i < $rowSet; $i++) {
    if($i > 0)
        $stmt->nextRowset();
    $response[] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

print_r($response);
```

Let say if the stored procedure `test()` returns 4 result set then you need to modified the value of `$rowSet = 4`, else the default value will be `1`